# spaCy Value Error: [E1041] Expected a string, Doc, or bytes as input, but got: <class 'float'>

Tags: machine-learning, vectorization, spacy, valueerror

I am trying to vectorize a Chinese-language input using spaCy.

My code is as follows:

```html
nlp = spacy.load('zh_core_web_md')

def tokenize_and_vectorize_textZH(text):
    clean_tokensZH = []
    for token in nlp(text):
        if (not token.is_stop) & (token.lemma_ != '-PRON-') & (not token.is_punct):
          # -PRON- is a special all inclusive lemma spaCy uses for any pronoun, we want to exclude these
            if (len(token.vector) != 300):
              print(token)
            clean_tokensZH.append(token.vector)
    return np.array(clean_tokensZH)
    
    
all_summmed_vecsZH = []

def sum_vecsZH(input):
  tokenized_vectorsZH = input.apply(tokenize_and_vectorize_textZH)
  tokenized_vectorZH = tokenized_vectorsZH.to_numpy()

  print(len(tokenized_vectorsZH))
  #print(type(tokenized_vectors))

  for row in tokenized_vectorsZH:

    #print(row)

    summed_vecZH = [0]*300 # start out as a list of 300 zeros

    for vec in row: # loop through each vector corresponding to each token in the row
      #if (len(vec) != 300):
        #print(vec)
      summed_vecZH += vec

    all_summmed_vecs.append(summed_vecZH)

  #print(tokenized_vectors[0][0].vector)
  
  
#@title Applying Vectorization
sum_vecsZH(X_trainZH)
print(all_summmed_vecs)

sum_vecsZH(y_trainZH)
print(all_summmed_vecs)

sum_vecsZH(X_testZH)
print(all_summmed_vecs)

sum_vecsZH(y_testZH)
print(all_summmed_vecs)
```

My intended output of the last 8 lines should be similar to this:
33384
33384
14308
14308

Here is a sample from my data:

| not_cyberbullying | 你看起来像个吉普赛人抱歉，我不抱歉 |
| --- | --- |
| not_cyberbullying | RT @Kurdsnews：土耳其国家在过去11年中杀害了241名儿童 http/t.co/JlvkE1epws #news ##GoogleÇeviriciTopluluğuKürtçeyideE... |
| Gender | 如果我叫你 婊子 你就生气了，那就别叫自己 咕咕女. |

What is the cause of the error?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide code we can copy and paste, as well as an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can replicate the problem and what you want your desired solution to look like.

Comment: Thank you for supplying code. Could you please also supply sample data that raises the exception? For example, what does `X_trainZH` look like?

Comment: I have attached an image. The dataset is a multi-class classification of translated Chinese tweets.

Comment: Please avoid sharing images of data as it is difficult to use them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/6509519

Comment: Updated. Tell me if you want any more.